# why rails force me to use bundle exec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to run my rake command using "rake routes"

but rails generate the following error

```
** Invoke routes (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant ActiveAdmin
/Users/aaalsubaie/Sites/Posnegs/config/initializers/active_admin.rb:1
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:588
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:587
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `run_initializers'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `send'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/Users/aaalsubaie/Sites/Posnegs/config/environment.rb:5
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:292:in `initialize_tasks'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33
/usr/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:23
Tasks: TOP => routes => environment
```

the strange thing is when I run "bundle exec rake routes"
it work correctly! I face this error in my development/production env

Answer (score 2):

Dependencies on specific versions of gems create a chicken and egg situation where the wrong version of a gem may be loaded before the app discovers that it  needs a different one.  `bundle exec` helps get off on the right foot.   see http://yehudakatz.com/2011/05/30/gem-versioning-and-bundler-doing-it-right/

Comment: is there an option to execute once and resolve all dependencies? then I dont need to use bundle exec anymore.

Comment: That article explained some of them.  use binstubs and change your path to check them first.  Or use oh-my-zsh as a shell, as it can automatically help you.  Or, if you use rvm, add the binstubs to your .rvmrc file.   I just alias 'be' to 'bundle exec' and run things as 'be rake'.   The only other option is to remove all conflicting gems that are not listed in your Gemfile.lock

Comment: thanks I dont mind write bundle exec in front of the executables. the problem is when I deploy with Cap deploy:cold is doesnot use it and this generate errors like this live from my site http://dev.ajhezaty.com/

Comment: As per http://gembundler.com/deploying.html you need to add `require "bundler/capistrano"` to your deploy.rb

Answer (score 2):

If you use rvm, you can use `bundle install --binstubs` and then you don't have to do bundle exec anymore.  See [this post](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/15346721484/use-bundlers-binstubs) for details.

Don't forget to add the bin directory to your gitignore file.

Comment: I am not using rvm. do you have any option for me other than this my rails v = 3.2.3 and my ruby v = ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [universal-darwin11.0]

Comment: You can use binstubs without rvm - bundle's home page may help -  http://gembundler.com/